# Cant change string value to variable with string value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox-api

I upload file to dropbox api, but it post on dropbox all directories from my computer since root folder. I mean you have folder of your project inside folder home, than user until you go to file sours folder. If I cut that structure library can't see that it is file, not string and give mistake message.
My code is:

```
def upload_file(project_id, filename, dropbox_token):
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(dropbox_token)
    file_path = os.path.abspath(filename)
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        dbx.files_upload(f.read(), file_path, mute=True)
        link = dbx.files_get_temporary_link(path=file_path).link
        return link
```

It works, but I need something like:

```
file_path = os.path.abspath(filename)
    chunks = file_path.split("/")
    name, dir = chunks[-1], chunks[-2]
```

which gives me mistake like:

```
dropbox.exceptions.ApiError: ApiError('433249b1617c031b29c3a7f4f3bf3847', GetTemporaryLinkError('path', LookupError('not_found', None)))
```

How could I make only parent folder and filename in the path?

For example if I have

```
/home/user/project/file.txt
```

I need

```
/project/file.txt
```

Comment: what is the value of `file_path` before you split it?

Comment: smthing like home/user/project/file.txt, but I need only /project/file.txt

Comment: then you probably don't need to pass all this information above, just [edit] your question to explain: I have this, and I want that, I tried that, that gave me this... shorter, clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `/home/user/project/file.txt` and you need `/project/file.txt`

I would split according to os default separator (so it would work with windows paths as well), then reformat only the 2 last parts with the proper format (sep+path) and join that.

```
import os
#os.sep = "/"  # if you want to test that on Windows
s = "/home/user/project/file.txt"
path_end = "".join(["{}{}".format(os.sep,x) for x in s.split(os.sep)[-2:]])
```

result:

```
/project/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the following code should works:

```
def upload_file(project_id, filename, dropbox_token):
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(dropbox_token)
    abs_path = os.path.abspath(filename)

    directory, file = os.path.split(abs_path)
    _, directory = os.path.split(directory)
    dropbox_path = os.path.join(directory, file)

    with open(abs_path, "rb") as f:
        dbx.files_upload(f.read(), dropbox_path, mute=True)
        link = dbx.files_get_temporary_link(path=dropbox_path).link
        return link
```